# Codebuild Insufficient Permissions: Account A calling step function in Account B

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-step-functions

I am currently trying to add a CodeBuild Action Step (Invoking a Step Function) in my CodePipeline deployment process. Specifically, I have a Codepipeline resource in Account A and I have a stepfunction defined in Account B. I want to be able to call my Stepfunction by using the CodeBuild Action step, but I am getting a "Insufficient Permissions Error". The error is below:

```
Insufficient permissions
An API call to StepFunctions.describeStateMachine (RequestId: XXX) returned a AccessDeniedException error: User: arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNTA:assumed-role/SplitUnitMainStack-pipelinePipelinesplitdeployunit-YVFTJZ8E0Z5U/1640984444652 is not authorized to access this resource
```

Here is what the permissions looks like for Role : arn:aws:iam::782665913187:role/SplitUnitMainStack-pipelinePipelinesplitdeployunit-YVFTJZ8E0Z5U

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTB:role/ExecuteUnitStepFunction"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is what the ExecuteUnitStepFunction Role looks like, which is defined in Account B

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "states:StartExecution",
                "states:StartSyncExecution",
                "states:DescribeStateMachine"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-west-1:ACCOUNTB:stateMachine:SimpleStateMachineE8E2CF40-TzPjbhdrazrn",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Trust Relationship for this role is this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTA:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing in order to give CodeBuild cross-account permissions to execution my Step function. One thing I am not sure about is that in the error, there is set of numbers following the role (1640984444652). I am not sure if this is impacting the permissions or if I am missing a step in order to execute a Step Function across accounts using a CodeBuild action.

Comment: What are the permissions for the codebuild itself, not the pipeline?

Comment: I believe the role posted above is the role used by Codebuild. The name is a little deceptive because i deployed the pipeline using CDK, and  I named the identifier with the tag "pipeline". Im not sure how to confirm that this role is used by Codebuild.

Comment: Go to AWS console, CodeBuild and check there what role your CB is using.